# Unexpected behavior from simple c while loop

Tags: c

I have enjoyed using GNU Linux for about a year now and thought that I would delve deeper by learning more about the programming language, C, that many Linux internals were made with. Today, I made a simple program that was supposed to help me understand while loops but has instead confused me. The goal of the program was quite simple: ask the user to enter one character per line until they entered the 'magic' character 'g', at which time the application would close. Here is what I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    char user_input;

    while (user_input != 'g') {
        printf("Please enter a character: ");
        scanf("%c", &user_input);
    }

    printf("You guessed the magic char, \'g\'!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I expected that, when run, the application would behave like the following:

```
Please enter a character: d
Please enter a character: dddd
Please enter a character: g
You guessed the magic char, 'g'!
```

However, this is the behavior I get:

```
Please enter a character: d
Please enter a character: dd
Please enter a character: Please enter a character: Please enter a character:
Please enter a character: Please enter a character: Please enter a character: g
```

It seems that, when the application encounters an input of 'n' characters, it appends 'Please enter a character: ' to its output 'n' times. Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I can do to prevent this behavior?

Based on L.P.'s answer, I have modified my code to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clear_buffer();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char user_input = '\0';

    do {
        printf("Enter guess: ");
        scanf("%c", &user_input);
        clear_buffer();
    } while (user_input != 'g');

    return 0;
}

void clear_buffer()
{
    while(getchar() != '\n' && getchar() != EOF);
}
```

However, when I enter something like:
    Please enter character: dddd
and press enter, I am given a newline that is blank until I press enter again...is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I suppose: When you entered "d"+return as well as "dd" + return in every loop only one char is consumed by scanf - the others are buffered (and, thus, automatically consumed in the next loop).

Comment: OK. That makes sense. How would I change my code to resolve that?

Comment: `user_input` should be initialized, such as `char user_input = '\0';`

Comment: Note that `user_input` is undefined for the first run of the loop. Automatic variables are not initialized. So, it would be better to use a `do .. while` loop or initialize `user_input` to an uncritical value, e.g. `'\0'`.

Comment: @DuncanG.Britton Always read whole lines from the user, e.g. with `fgets`.

Comment: Maybe instead of `scanf`, use `getchar`.

Comment: There's a bug in `clear_buffer`.  Should be something like `while(((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things. 
One: Never run a test on an uninitialized variable. 
Two: Clear the buffer. It's a minor annoyance. And is the reason why you're having that behavior.
While I agree with the snippet of code that is above, I have a habit of not liking to place things like this directly, when , due to it's heavy use, it should be made into a function.

```
void clearBuffer() {                                   
  int c;                   
  while(((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF));                                                     
}
```

Forgot to add at first that you should be running the clearBuffer() function after you have scanned a character in using the scanf() function.

Never test a variable in c, or for good practice in most any other languages either, without initializing it first.

So you should be using a do-while loop instead of a while loop. That will help keep you from, as said above in the comments experiencing unexpected behaviors from your code, and is overall good practice for when things start to get way more complex.

Comment: Rewrote the comment, started wriitng it on my phone, and noticed that it was a nuisance. Hopefully I cleared things up a bit more. & @FiddlingBits why did you initialize it as the null character? Never really seen that point as useful to be honest.

Comment: Could have been anything really, other than `'g'` of course.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Yes the stdin buffer should be cleared for the case that he is employing. Least that's how I was taught initially, then I learned some better safe guards but that is in itself, not what he was asking for in the question, I think. The code snippet I was speaking of was the snippet by 'Blue Mopon' that was stated prior to mine. Don't know as of yet how to point to others comments that are not within the context of my own, if that is in itself even possible.

Comment: I was asking which buffer, because I wanted you to add that to your answer. :-D

Comment: `clearBuffer` has a minor bug.  Should be written `while(((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF)); `

Comment: And the type of `c` should be `int`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I see the point for it. Saves a function call, and is in itself more efficient for that, my initial code did not run the check for EOF since it seemed unlikely that the poster needed to run it, and saw the c mistake right after since chars can't store the EOF value...

Comment: @FiddlingBits Even this answer is proposing exactly what I have? I don't think this will accept `abcdg` either.

Comment: @BlueMoon You're right, but since you're in the elite club, I'm picking on you. :-D

Comment: What do you mean @BlueMoon it takes that string in, and throws out everything but 'a'. It's not supposed to accept the whole thing, if that is what you mean, I'm not too sure.

Comment: I saw that though, I stated that it saves a function call, and I do know that it could cause lag in the program, awaiting input from the user, if it doesn't end in a proper manner, my point was that I initially wasn't checking for EOF just end of line/user Input so the second function call was placed there mistakenly, don't worry one test run through of the code showed me my mistake lol.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I didn't know I was in any sort of club, let alone the *elite* ones :)

Answer (score 3):

Read all characters from the buffer, if any, until the newline char and discard them:

```
int c;

....

        scanf("%c", &user_input);
        while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
```

As noted in the comments, you need to initialize `user_input` with something. Automatic variables are not initialized in C.

Comment: Can you add more code?  Not sure why you're using `scanf` on `user_input` and `getchar` on `c`.  Maybe you're assuming `'g'` always comes first?

Comment: That's all the code there is. Rest is just what OP has. `c` doesn't serve any purpose. It's just used to read any *extra* chars, if any.

Comment: What if `'g'` is in `c`?

Comment: It will be discarded. I don't think OP wants the inputs like `abcdg` to be a valid case.

Comment: OP isn't very descriptive in his requirements, but I'm assuming `'g'` should be found at any location, IMHO. :-D

Answer (score 2):

If you want the simple answer: `scanf(" %c", &user_input);` worked just fine (keep in mind the space character before `%c`). This only works if the user is entering characters one at a time. The more formal approach has already been mentioned by *Blue Moon*.

This happens due to `scanf` consuming the `\n` character on the first character entered. When you enter in a character then hit enter, scanf will consume the character up to the newline. However the newline is still out in the input buffer which is consumed by `scanf` on the next `while` loop iteration.